# scanf strings to structure char pointer

Tags: c, scanf

```
typedef struct Std{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    int yearOfBirth;
} Std;
[...]
Std* obj = (Std*)calloc(1, sizeof(Std));
scanf("%s", obj->name);
scanf("%s", obj->surname);
scanf("%d", obj->yearOfBirth);
```

Dont work. How make `scanf` save the strings to the structure's fields?

Comment: "Dont work" is not a very good problem description. You need to allocate space for the strings that `name` and `surname` point to.  As they stand, their values are undefined and they're invalid pointers. Then you need to provide the address of `obj->yearOfBirth` for that `scanf` to work: `scanf("%d", obj->yearOfBirth);` --> `scanf("%d", &obj->yearOfBirth);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `calloc ()` you allocated for `obj` the memory space needed by `Std` structure. But with this action you are not allocating the two `char *` pointers it contains: `name` and `surname`.

Accessing them with scanf means writing to undefined location, and this probably leads to a segmentation fault.

So, just `malloc ()` to them enough space to contain name and surname:

```
typedef struct Std{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    int yearOfBirth;
} Std;

Std* obj = calloc(1, sizeof(Std));
obj->name = malloc(50*sizeof char);
obj->surname = malloc(50*sizeof char);

scanf("%49s", obj->name);
scanf("%49s", obj->surname);
```

Some notes:

- In C, casting the result of `malloc` is not required. It is instead required in C++, so you can omit it unless you are using a C++ compiler
- `sizeof char` is 1. I added it to hilight the type ypu are allocating. It can be omitted or otherwise `sizeof(obj->name`)` can be used
- With `%49s` I make sure that at most 49 characters + the string terminator are written in my char arrays, avoiding undesirable out of bounds access

As an alternative, you could change the `Std` definition in order to statically define the size of `name` and `surname` char arrays:

```
typedef struct Std{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int yearOfBirth;
} Std;

scanf("%49s", obj->name);
scanf("%49s", obj->surname);
```

Comment: See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Where did the OP say they were using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @lurker they didn't say it. As I have written I know it because they casted to Std the result of calloc in order to remove warning/error. ;) Even out of beginners area this is pretty common (for example... the embedded code of my company's fw)

Comment: @lurker ... anyway I removed the casting and rephrased the description. I keep mentioning the C++ compiler note in case op is actually using it and gets puzzled by the warning/error